# trouble installing biopython

Tags: python-2.7, biopython

I'm following the directions from the Biopython website (http://biopython.org/wiki/Download) but I keep getting an error during installation. I have python 2.7 installed on my laptop.

```
python2.7 -m pip install biopython
```

I just get the error:

```
No module named pip
```

I looked up this error and tried something stack overflow suggested:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

But I just got another error:

```
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

Comment: Check that pip is installed correctly

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Check [here](https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc/chapter_12/installing_pip.html) for a good resource (it depends on your OS)

Comment: I have python version 2.7.10 so shouldn't that include pip?

Comment: It looks like this may have worked: sudo easy_install pip

Comment: What is your operating system? Apparently you're not using a linux distribution to use `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have Python 2.7.9 onwards this should automatically install pip for you:

```
python -m ensurepip
```

It would be useful to know what Operating System you have to help improve the instructions here.

Answer (score 0):

Many dependency issues are solved [here at Annaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/download/) where you fetch python, lots of nice libs, etc.. Install it accordingly to your platform.. windows, Linux or Mac OS.

Biopython is installed by Annaconda by default (including matplotlib and other dependencies)... if I recall correctly. Otherwise its from commandline `conda search biopython` and or `conda install pip`. And then commandline `pip install biopython`.